# How did Anne know Peter was not at work?

Tags: office-space

In the beginning of the film, Peter was hypnotized and decided not to show up on Saturday. He got lots of messages from his boss asking why he didn't show up. He also got one from his girlfriend Anne, who complained that he didn't go to work today.

How did Anne know he wasn't at work? Did she work at Initech as well?

Comment: Possibly because the company called her when they couldn't reach him? (Perhaps she was listed as an emergency contact?)

Comment: She does not level Peter a message.  She calls him at home and talks to him.  She probably tried him on his work phone and when he didn't answer she called him at home.  The days when people had "land lines".

Comment: yeah but why did she know he had to work on saturday?

Comment: @ToddWilcox, here's the scene in question - https://youtu.be/CLxu2hVzdX0?t=83.  They talk first, then she calls back and leaves a message.

Comment: @Mark You're right. I forgot it was two calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all makes sense if you think it like this. Anne went to therapy session with Peter. Well it's not shown on screen but Peter might have shared his problems and that he was being called to office on holidays too and how he hates his job and his boss.

Borrowing from Mark's comment, she might have called him at office and upon being unresponsive she called him at his home.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is almost certainly the answer. She says "It's 3:30 why aren't you at work?" It's very likely she called his work number and he didn't answer, and then she tried him at home and when he answered, she then knew he was home but not why.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: OP's question was 'How did Anne know?'. Second para supports the assumption that 'Anne must have known because Peter shared it during therapy.'